# error: prototype for XXX does not match any in class YYY

Tags: c++, poo

Tengo una pregunta sobre porque mi código no corre y me da el siguiente error:

> main.cpp:26:1: error: prototype for ‘Empleado::Empleado(std::string, std::string, int, int, std::string, int, int, int, std::string)’ does not match any in class ‘Empleado’
> Empleado::Empleado(string _nombre,string _apellidos,int _DNI,int _ID,string _direccion,int _tiempoactivo,int _telefono,int _salario,string _supervisor){

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Empleado{
    protected:
        //Atributos
        string nombre;
        string apellidos;
        int DNI;
        int ID;
        string direccion;
        int tiempoactivo;
        int telefono;
        int salario;
        string supervisor;
    public:
        //Constructor y Destructor
        Empleado();
        ~Empleado();
        //Metodos
        virtual void Get_Empleado();
        virtual void Cambiar_Supervisor();
        virtual void Incrementar_Salario();
};

Empleado::Empleado(string _nombre,string _apellidos,int _DNI,int _ID,string _direccion,int _tiempoactivo,int _telefono,int _salario,string _supervisor){
    nombre = _nombre;
    apellidos = _apellidos;
    DNI = _DNI;
    ID = _ID
    direccion = _direccion;
    tiempoactivo = _tiempoactivo;
    telefono = _telefono;
    salario = _salario;
    supervisor = _supervisor;
}

void Empleado::Get_Empleado(){
    cout<<"EMPLEADO"<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Apellidos: "<<apellidos<<endl;
    cout<<"DNI: "<<DNI<<endl;
    cout<<"Direccion: "<<direccion<<endl;
    cout<<"Tiempo Activo en meses: "<<tiempoactivo<<endl;
    cout<<"Telefono: "<<telefono<<endl;
    cout<<"Salario: "<<salario<<endl;
    cout<<"Supervisor: "<<supervisor<<endl;
}

void Empleado::Incrementar_Salario(){
    int _s;
    cout<<"Ingresa el nuevo salario"<<endl;
    cin>>_s;
    
    salario = _s;
    
    cout<<"El nuevo salario es: "<<salario;
}

void Empleado::Cambiar_Supervisor(){
    string s;
    cout<<"Ingresa el nuevo supervisor"<<endl;
    cin>>s;
    
    supervisor = s;
    
    cout<<"El nuevo supervisor es: "<<supervisor;
}

int main()
{
    string nombre;
    string apellidos;
    int DNI;
    int ID;
    string direccion;
    int tiempoactivo;
    int telefono;
    int salario;
    string supervisor;
        
    cout<<"Ingresa nombre del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"Ingresa apellidos del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>apellidos;
    cout<<"Ingresa DNI del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>DNI;
    cout<<"Ingresa ID del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>ID;
    cout<<"Ingresa direccion del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>direccion;
    cout<<"Ingresa tiempo activo en meses del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>tiempoactivo;
    cout<<"Ingresa telefono del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>telefono;
    cout<<"Ingresa salario del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>salario;
    cout<<"Ingresa supervisor del empleado"<<endl;
    cin>>supervisor;
    
    Empleado *vector[1];
    
    vector[0] = new Empleado(nombre,apellidos,DNI,ID,direccion,tiempoactivo,telefono,salario,supervisor);
    
    vector[0]->Get_Empleado();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Estoy intentando hacer herencia con la clase Empleado, pero no se porque el constructor me da un error de que no tiene que ver con la clase, cuando lo reviso veo que todo esta bien pero me sigue dando ese error y no se como corregirlo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que se debe a que el constructor (la firma, los parámetros y sus tipos) como esta definido en la clase (sin ningún parámetro) es diferente a la implementación (que tiene varios parametros).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En C++, las funciones pueden definirse de 2 formas: *inline* o *no-inline*. En tu caso, estás usando la 2º forma.

Para funciones *no-inline*, estas **necesitan** ser declaradas con anterioridad a cualquier uso, incluyendo su definición.

Tu problema es que estás definiendo tu función

```
Empleado::Empleado(string _nombre,string _apellidos,int _DNI,int _ID,string _direccion,int _tiempoactivo,int _telefono,int _salario,string _supervisor)
```

**sin que esté declarada** con anterioridad.

Simplemente, declárala **antes** de definirla:

```
class Empleado{
    ...
    public:
        //Constructor y Destructor
        Empleado();
        ~Empleado();
        // AQUÍ
        Empleado::Empleado(string _nombre,string _apellidos,int _DNI,int _ID,string _direccion,int _tiempoactivo,int _telefono,int _salario,string _supervisor);
        ...
```

Comment: Funciono!, Tuve solo que declararla como "Empleado('propiedades')" para que pudiera leerlo, muchas gracias!